# Getting a error for captcha image

Tags: php, captcha

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagettfbbox()
```

But it is loading in local server perfectly .

This is my web url.

http://mc-serverreviews.com/test/contact.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server may not have [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library installed.